# Unable to delete a huge UPDATE.APP file on Huawei P8lite

Tags: huawei, files, delete

My Huawei P8lite running on EMUI version 4.0 and Android 6.0 Marshmallow is low on disk space. I noticed there's a huge UPDATE.APP file, it's taking 2.55 GB.

[image: screenshot of a file manager showing the file]

I tried to delete it, but it shows an error:

> Error while deleting the file "UPDATE.APP".

How to delete this file?

Comment: Where is that file? Can you post the absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some good file explorer like [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) and then try to delete the file, if direct deletion doesn't work then try renaming the file, then delete it. If that doesn't work then plug your phone into your computer and delete it from there. If nothing works then you might need root access to delete it.